# Как добавить два отношения один-к-нулю между двумя таблицами в EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

У меня есть две таблицы, связанные отношением один-к-одному. POCO класс для основной таблицы *Message*.

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    public virtual MessageContent MessageContent {get;set;}
}
```

И класс для связанной таблицы *MessageContent*:

```
 public class MessageContent
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey]
    public Guid MessageId {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    public virtual Message Message {get;set;}
}
```

Как написано выше работает хорошо. Но мне нужно добавить еще два отношения один-к-одному(нулю) из *MessageContent* на *Message*:

```
public class MessageContent
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey]
    public Guid MessageId {get; set;}
    //Other fields
    public virtual Message Message {get;set;}

    public virtual Message Reason {get;set;}
    public Guid? ReasonId {get;set;}

    public virtual Message Report {get;set;}
    public Guid? ReportId {get;set;}
}
```

Пробовал немного менять код. При генерации модели выскакивает исключение или нарушается изначальное отношение один-к-одному.
Как к существующей модели добавить еще два отношения 1...0 из MessageContent на Message?

Comment: русский язык не смущает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос - переведите его на русский язык.

Comment: Извините за английский...

Comment: @chuk.huck извините за любопытство, но что вас побудило задавать вопрос на англ языке, если вы вполне владеете русским?

Comment: Это мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow. Сначала пытался задать вопрос на обычном, потом магия перенесла на overflow на русском, ну и так далее)))

Comment: Ребята, всем спасибо. Очень помогли)).

Comment: Ой, опять ошибся. Теперь же надо было писать на английском)))

Comment: Если кому надо, вот ссылка http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129845/how-to-create-two-relations-one-to-zero-between-two-tables-in-ef?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: А что за отношение такое 1 к 0? 1-1 — знаю, 1-М — знаю, М-М знаю. Что за 1 к 0?

Comment: Это значит, что значение внешнего ключа может быть null. Ответ на данный вопрос уже найден. Ссылка на решение представлена ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильное описание класса MessageContent:

```
public class MessageContent
{
[Key]
[ForeignKey("Message")]
public Guid MessageId {get; set;}
//Other fields
public virtual Message Message {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("Reason")]
public Guid? ReasonId {get;set;}
public virtual Message Reason {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("Report")]
public Guid? ReportId {get;set;}
public virtual Message Report {get;set;}
}
```

Но если оставить так, то появится исключение при создании модели, так как создается кольцевая ссылка. Чтобы разрешить эту проблему, надо добавить следующий код:

```
        modelBuilder.
            Entity<Message>().
            HasRequired(m => m.MessageContent).
            WithRequiredDependent(d=>d.MessageId);
```